# codeigniter how to join 3 table and display from user id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

### [Mydatabase image click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH0W3.jpg)

i want to display

group1

- shop1
- shop2
- shop3

group2

- shop1
- shop2
- shop3
- shop5

group2

- .....
- ....
- ....

---

```
function getGroups($user_id) {

    $this->db->select ( '*' ); 
    $this->db->from ( 'user' );
    $this->db->join ( 'groups', 'groups.user_id = user.id');
    $this->db->join ( 'shop', 'shop.group_id = groups.group_id');
    $this->db->where('user.id',$user_id);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: group by groups.id,shop.id order by groups.id

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for Answer.
I may not be don't understand for the above Answer.
I use this method instead.
It may not be the correct way.
work for me.

```
function getGroups($user_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('groups');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->order_by('group_id', 'ASC');
    $group_data = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    foreach($group_data as $key=>$value){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('shop');
        $this->db->where('group_id', $value['group_id']);
        $this->db->order_by('shop_id', 'ASC');
        $shop_data = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        $my_group[$key]['group_name'] = $value['group_name'];
        $my_group[$key]['group_id'] = $value['group_id'];
        $my_group[$key]['group_shop'] = $shop_data;


    }
    return $my_group;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `group by groups.id,shop.id and order by groups.id`.

```
function getGroups($user_id) {
    $this->db->select ( '*' ); 
    $this->db->from ( 'user' );
    $this->db->join ( 'groups', 'groups.user_id = user.id');
    $this->db->join ( 'shop', 'shop.group_id = groups.group_id');
    $this->db->where('user.id',$user_id);
    $this->db->group_by(array('groups.id','shop.id'));
    $this->db->order_by("groups.id", "desc");
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try   this..

```
function getGroups($user_id)
 {
    $this->db->select ( '*' ); 
    $this->db->from ( 'user' );
    $this->db->join ( 'groups', 'groups.user_id = user.user_id');
    $this->db->join ( 'shop', 'shop.group_id = groups.group_id');
    $this->db->where('user.user_id',$user_id);
    $this->db->group_by(array('groups.id','shop.id'));
    $this->db->order_by("groups.id", "desc");
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```